# Date format gets inserted in database + 4 hours

Tags: javascript, datetime, fullcalendar, utc, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullcalendar (https://fullcalendar.io).
When I drop an event from one time to another, the hour changes + 4 hours. But this doesn't happen when I click on a date and add an event.

This is my "eventDrop" event:

```
eventDrop: function(eventDropInfo) {

    console.log(eventDropInfo);
    $.ajax({
          url: 'update.php',
          data: 'id='+ eventDropInfo.event.id+'title='+ eventDropInfo.event.title+'&start='+ eventDropInfo.event.start.toISOString()+'&allDay='+ eventDropInfo.event.allDay,                                                   
          type: "POST",
          success: function(json) {

            alert('success');

           calendar.refetchEvents();
              }
  });

  },
```

My Update.php file is as follows:

```
// get database connection
require_once 'api/config/connection.php';

// Check user information
$fusername = $_SESSION['fusername'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fusername=:fusername;");
$stmt->bindParam(':fusername', $fusername);
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


if(isset($_POST["id"])){

$start_event = $_POST['start'];
$end_event = $_POST['end'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$allDay = $_POST['allDay'];

// Check user information
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE events SET start_event=:start_event, end_event=:end_event, allDay=:allDay WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':start_event', $start_event);
$stmt->bindParam(':end_event', $end_event);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':allDay', $allDay);
$stmt->execute();

}
```

The event.start in the console is showing as:
start: Tue Jul 30 2019 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

But when I apply the ".toISOString" it gets converted to "2019-07-30T12:00:00.000Z" and is posted to the database as 2019-07-30 12:00:00(4 hours ahead).

I also noticed than when I click on a date cell to add an event, using console.log I get from the event object startStr and endStr as follows:

*start: Sun Aug 04 2019 05:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)*

*end: Sun Aug 04 2019 06:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)*

*startStr: "2019-08-04T05:30:00-04:00"*

*endStr: "2019-08-04T06:00:00-04:00"*

**This (above) is EXACTLY how I want my dates to be formatted when I drop an event into a date cell.**

But instead, when I am using toISOString my datetime is converting to "T12:00:00.000Z" with the (Z) instead of adding the time offsite at the end. How are they converted to "T05:30:00-04:00"? I mean, I just need the date to be the XX:XX:XX, and be entered into the database as such.

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toISOString() uses UTC-0 and adjusts the date accordingly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: I see now. Is there a way to actually show the time on the calendar without changing it to UTC-0? I mean, I am dragging the event to the 8am slot, but it changes it to 12pm time once it enters the database. :-(

So, right now my console log displays this: 
start: Wed Jul 31 2019 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) but after I apply the toISOString() it gets changed to 12:00:00.

Comment: I'd store the date/time in UTC-0 in the database and handle the offset at the business layer.  That way it's standardized in the database and localized for users.  It looks like FullCalendar has some support for time zones.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing

Comment: Thanks Dave. The problem is that the date/time I getting from fullcalendar is mixed up. I just updated the question above. If you could please re-read. I appreciate your attention and help. ;-)

Comment: Your question and the answer really haven't changed.  Fullcalendar.io [appears to be] using local time zones, but your code is explicitly changing the time to UTC-0 when calling the toISOString() method.  So you need to either make all of the dates go to UTC-4 or all of the dates go to UTC-0.  I assume you want them all to be UTC-4, so remove the toISOString() method from your update statement.  That'll pass the event date object (not the string) to update.php.

Comment: I don't have that source code handy, so I don't know if it'll accept it, but try.  If it doesn't, you'll have to format the data manually.  You can do this a number of ways, but fullcalendar.io has a plugin for moment.js which makes this pretty easy.  A quick search will show you the syntax.